# puppeteer overridePermissions clipboard-read not working on createIncognitoBrowserContext()

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

The following code is viable for reading the clipboard in headless/headfull:

```js
var context = await client.defaultBrowserContext();
await context.overridePermissions('http://localhost', ['clipboard-read']);
page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto( 'http://localhost/test/', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 35000});
// click button for clipboard..
let clipboard = await page.evaluate(`(async () => await navigator.clipboard.readText())()`);
```

But when you later start incognito its not working anymore:

```js
const incognito = await client.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
page = await incognito.newPage();
```

and you get:

- DOMException: Read permission denied.

I currently try to figure out to combine both.. Anybody know how to set overridePermissions inside of the new incognito window?

Please notice I do not want to use the incognito chrome arg at the start. I want to manually create new incognito pages inside of my scripts with correct overridePermissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions work only in the context in which you set the permissions. You would also have to set the permissions for the incognito context.

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

const url = 'https://www.google.com'
const permissions = ['clipboard-read']

await puppeteer.launch()
  .then(browser => browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext())
  .then(context => context.overridePermissions(url, permissions) 
    .then(_ => context.newPage()))
  .then(page => page.goto(url)
    .then(_ => /* code that uses permissions */))
```

Feel free to take a look at the documentation for more information:

[BrowserContext](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.browsercontext)

[BrowserContext.overridePermissions](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.browsercontext.overridepermissions)

[Browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.browser.createincognitobrowsercontext)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the very same issue. Here's a minimal reproducible example.
Nodejs version: v16.13.1
puppeteer version: puppeteer@14.4.1

```
  'use strict';
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  const URL = 'https://google.com';
  (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const context = browser.defaultBrowserContext();
      context.overridePermissions(URL, ['clipboard-read', 'clipboard-write'])
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto(URL, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
      });
  
      await page.evaluate(() => navigator.clipboard.writeText("Injected"));
  
      const value = await page.evaluate(() => navigator.clipboard.readText());
      console.log(value);
  })();
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32143581)